# favicon вставка под все устройства

Tags: html

Дизайнер мне скинул папку с фавиконами, там их 42 штуки разных размеров.
как их правильно подключить?
Внутри некоторых папок имеется файл Conects.json, для чего он нужен.

Comment: Вы [точно воспроизвели имя файла](https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=%22conects.json%22)? Не `config.json`? Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Содержимое json файла не покажите? Я полагаю речь идет про иконки для Apple, Google, Windows плитки и прочих. Тогда в архиве должны быть файлы с "говорящими" названиями и размерами. Я подключаю так:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/android-chrome-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
<meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="/smalltile.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="/mediumtile.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="/widetile.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="/largetile.png" />
```

У Вас, скорее всего, будет аналогично, плюс дополнительные размеры и форматы.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем мусор делать в коде для каждого подключать? Достаточно иконки размером 16 на 16

```
<link id="page_favicon" href="http://site.com/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Comment: Это не "мусор", как вы выразились. Сделано это для лучшего отображения на разных устройствах. Именно за формулировку ответа ставлю вам минус.

Comment: На разных устройствах уважаемый, иконка будет отображаться одинаково хорошо, если она хорошо сделана. А за вашу Seo не грамотность вам большой минус. Лишние коды в теле страницы они же лишние килобайты замедляют скорость загрузки страницы.

Comment: Неграмотность в SEO, говорите? Зря вы так. В веб-разработке я что-то, да понимаю. Посмотрите на скриншот: https://yadi.sk/i/zasE9ULvphNYs . Браузер сам определяет, что ему нужно загружать. Ни о каких "килобайтах" ненужной информации речи не идет.

Comment: Последнюю строчку обвести забыл.